# Are orthogonal matrices unitary?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices, unitary-matrices

If we have an orthogonal square matrix, A, and some c in the complex numbers with |c| = 1, how do we know cA is unitary?

Comment: if $A$ is real, then yes, $cA$ is unitary, and you can see it just using the definition

Comment: Definitions are your friends.  Do you know the definition of a *unitary* matrix?

Comment: Could you please accept my answer if it is sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $AA^T = I $ and $A^TA = I$ (since $A$ is orthogonal). Then, $cA((cA)^\ast)^T = c\overline{c} AA^T = c\overline{c} I = I$ (since $|c| = 1$) (assuming $A$ is real). As also mentioned in the comments, one just has to use the definition of a unitary/orthogonal matrix.

Comment: but to show a matrix is unitary, do we not need A(A*)^T = I? As in (cA)[(cA)*]^T = I?

Comment: But I just showed that $AA^T = A^TA=I$, which is the condition for a unitary matrix